# How to synthesize a block of registers as ROM in verilog

Tags: verilog, synthesis, rom

Here is a bit from my verilog code

```
reg [17:0]FilterCoeffRam[95:0]; // Filter Coefficients   
reg [17:0]CoeffRam01[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam02[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam03[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam04[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam05[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam06[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam07[0:5]; 
reg [17:0]CoeffRam08[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam09[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam10[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam11[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam12[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam13[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam14[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam15[0:5];  
reg [17:0]CoeffRam16[0:5];  
integer k;

initial  
begin  
        $readmemh("FilterCoeff96.txt",FilterCoeffRam);  
        for(k=0; k<6; k=k+1)  
            begin  
           CoeffRam01[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k];  
            CoeffRam02[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+6];  
            CoeffRam03[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+12];  
            CoeffRam04[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+18];  
            CoeffRam05[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+24];  
            CoeffRam06[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+30];  
            CoeffRam07[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+36];  
            CoeffRam08[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+42];  
            CoeffRam09[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+48];  
            CoeffRam10[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+54];  
            CoeffRam11[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+60];  
            CoeffRam12[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+66];  
            CoeffRam13[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+72];  
            CoeffRam14[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+78];  
            CoeffRam15[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+84];  
            CoeffRam16[k]=FilterCoeffRam[k+90];  
         end  
    end
```

I am reading 96 18bit hex values from a txt file & storing them into FilterCoeffRam register.
Then i am dividing these coefficients equally in 16 registers. Ideally, these 16 6x18bit registers should be synthesized as ROMs. But the Synthesis report doesnt list these as ROM but as registers.

```
WARNING:Xst:1780 - Signal <FilterCoeffRam> is never used or assigned. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam16> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam15> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam14> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam13> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam12> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam11> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam10> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam09> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam08> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam07> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam06> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam05> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam04> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam03> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam02> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:1781 - Signal <CoeffRam01> is used but never assigned. Tied to default value.
```

How do i make sure they are inferred as ROMs & not registers

Answer (score 1):

I do not see from your report what makes you think they are registers.

Instead of a physical ROM macro you might just want to build a LUT (Look up table) which can be synthesised quite efficiently.

If you only need one of the coefficients at a time some thing similar to the following may be helpful:

```
always @* begin //Combinatorial block (no flip_flops)
   case( addr )
     0: coeff = 32'd23  ;
     1: coeff = 32'd43  ;
     2: coeff = 32'd255 ;
     // etc ...
end
```

Comment: No, i need 16 coefficients at a time. Hence i am dividing the 96 coeff into 16 smaller ROMs. But xilinx interprets it as registers & not ROM macro

Comment: @KharoBangdo then 16 Look up tables, if the coefficients are not reused.

Comment: The coefficients are reused & also I dont want to initialize them again after a reset. Hence i wanted a ROM since i'll be changing some inputs after reset. But what is wrong with my code using a for loop. Any idea?

Comment: I never use `initial` statements in synthesizable code, although I am aware that FPGAs use them for initial values rather than resets. What makes you think they are being implemented as Flip-flops? The report in your question does not show that. Can you update the question with the relevant report. You want the synthesis tool to give you a ROM, a LUT is not reprogrammable and is closer in structure to what you want, it may help guide the tool.

Comment: Those are the only lines in Synthesis report which mention the above registers. It list some other registers in my program as rom but not these reg. I'll try the LUT approach too, thanks

Comment: I relooked at the synthesis report & found that XST is indeed assigning a ROM macro. I want 16nos. of 6x18 bit ROMs but XST is assigning 2nos. of 6x36 bit & 4nos. of 6x54 bit ROMs. Although the total ROM size matches the application, but since i need 16 simultaneous coeffs to be read from ROM, that is bound to create problems no as i have only 6 ROMs synthesized. Am i correct?

Comment: If possible I would split the coeffs.txt in to 16 separate files then follow @EML's advice. or put the ROMS into to sub-modules in such away that you specify 16 read-back addresses, or your ROM structure might be able to supply all values at any time. I am not an FPGA expert, I only do ASIC design in verilog.

Answer (score 0):

Your first warning is telling you that the `readmemh` isn't working. Try reducing this to the simplest form, as per the XST docs:

```
reg [17:0] FilterCoeffRam [95:0];
initial begin
  $readmemh("coeffs.txt", FilterCoeffRam, 95, 0);
end
```

(the `begin`/`end` is obviously redundant as well). Next, you may well have to get rid of your `for` loop; XST may be having trouble unrolling this, in combination with the `readmemh`. You're effectively asking XST to treat the `CoeffRam0x` instances as ROMs, and I think it may get confused by that. It's not doing anything useful, anyway - try to handle this in the addressing logic. Third, don't expect this stuff to go in a specific 'ROM' - it will go in 27 LUTs in a V6, for example (ie. 27 mini-ROMs).

Comment: `begin`/`end`s add clarity to the code and cut down on bugs when extra lines of code are added. I think it is good practise to always use them especially when learning.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an always block and a clock otherwise a RAM will not be inferred. Synthesis tools can be picky when inferring RAMs, so make sure you follow the exact format given in the vendor documentation. Check out the XST User Guide for whatever version you are using: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_6/xst.pdf